# Cron tab doesn't run most of tasks

Tags: php, cron

I setup several cron jobs to make things work. laravel scheduler works perfectly but my other cronjobs not working at all.

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/cronjobs/index.php
```

when I run on the console `/usr/bin/php /var/www/cronjobs/index.php` it works properly. I checked executable php path with `which php` and gives me `/usr/bin/php` nothing wrong with path afaik. I tried to run php script as apache user `www-data` I opened crontab with `crontab -u www-data -e` and paste command there.. it didn't work too.

I also tried send dummy notify with crontab and it also didn't work either

**dummy example**

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send 'test'
```

both of them doesn't work. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Can you check the permission of index.php

Comment: @Ajith it's permission is `-rwxrwxr-x`

Answer (score 0):

The second command will not send notification as `cron` have no idea of your desktop environment.

The first command probably use some environment variables. So instead of run in command line you can try to create a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /path/to/user/home/.bashrc #you can try also .bash_profile
/usr/bin/php /var/www/cronjobs/index.php
```

and your cron to be like:

```
*/2 * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: Hi romeo, thank for the reply. I tried your solutions and nothing happened. I want to ask you something. Why we can't use notify-send command on crontab ? I'm using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Because `cron` do not assign terminal to this task. Try to set `echo test >/tmp/test` and check the file

Comment: even if there is a executable path ? then how it's able to execute php cli ?

Comment: With high probability=lity you have in shell some variables set by `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`